# How to disable gnome calendar integration with google?

Tags: gnome3, evolution, calendar, google

I want to remove Google calendar tasks from Gnome calendar. I never really configured Gnome to show Google tasks but I think Evolution automatically integrated them.

I did find some instructions on how to enable this integration, but they teach how to do it using Gnome's "online accounts" settings. I have no online account configured in my Gnome settings.

There are a few options on Evolution's account settings related to the calendar but they did not remove tasks from Gnome calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem for a while, I just went into evolution client, and deleted the google account from Preferences>accounts that solved it, the google authentication has not appeared so far, try it out.

I guess evolution will automatically integrate with gnome calendar, kind of sucks tho, it would be nice to opt-In, I don't really use calendars and when I stopped using evolution completely forgot thats when gnome started prompting for google calendar access. Your question helped me remember that, so thank you.